# What the purpose of `initSource`, `initSink` or `setSinkClock` in chiseltest test harness?

Tags: scala, chisel, chiseltest

In chisel-template [test example](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template/blob/main/src/test/scala/gcd/GCDSpec.scala) there are some init calls method for decoupled value:

```scala
class GCDSpec extends FreeSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {

  "Gcd should calculate proper greatest common denominator" in {
    test(new DecoupledGcd(16)) { dut =>
      dut.input.initSource()
      dut.input.setSourceClock(dut.clock)
      dut.output.initSink()
      dut.output.setSinkClock(dut.clock)

//...
```

I can't find documentation explained the purpose of these methods. Why do we have to «init source or sink» of decoupled input ?

The [api documentation](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/chiseltest/0.3.3/chiseltest/DecoupledDriver.html#setSourceClock(clock:chisel3.Clock):DecoupledDriver.this.type) is not filled with documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two init methods do the following
`dut.input.initSource()` sets input decoupled's valid signal to `false.B`
`dut.output.initSink()` sets output decoupled's ready signal to `false.B`
I think you could do these on your own manually.
The clock setting calls do a bit more complicated stuff in order to coordinate clock handling across `fork` calls which are typically used with the `enqueue`  and `dequeue` family of functions. It might be that this could be inferred from DUTs but detecting the `decoupled` interfaces is currently a bit hard to do.

The boilerplate calls to these function can be more succinctly specified as

```
  dut.input.initSource().setSourceClock(dut.clock)
  dut.output.initSink().setSinkClock(dut.clock)
```

since the `initSource` and `initSync` return the port decoupled port

As to documentation, this should definitely be improved for the decoupled helpers. I have added a note to do this to an existing [documentation issue](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2/issues/352)